# Unable to play audio in xcode 6 swift

Tags: xcode, audio, swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlaySoundViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioplayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie_quote", ofType: "mp3") {
            var fileUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
            audioplayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileUrl, error: nil)


        }else{
        println("path file is empty")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func PlaySoundSlow(sender: UIButton) {
        audioplayer.play()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally make a sound class, then use a function to call the sound into play, like this:

Sound Class:

```
class Sound {
    //properties
    var fileName = ""
    var fileExtension = ""

    //custom init
    init(fileName: String, fileExtension: String) {
        self.fileName = fileName
        self.fileExtension = fileExtension
    }
}
```

playSound Function:

> // requires AVAudioPlayer? instance
>
> // requires AVFoundation import
>
> // requires AVAudioPlayerDelegate
>
> var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer()
>
> func playSound (sound: Sound) {
>
> let dispatchQueue =
>       dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
>
> ```
> dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, {[weak self] in
>     let mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
>
>     /* Find the location of our file to feed to the audio player */
>     let filePath = mainBundle.pathForResource(sound.fileName, ofType:sound.fileExtension)
>
>     if let path = filePath{
>         let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
>
>         var error:NSError?
>
>         /* Start the audio player */
>         self!.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: fileData, error: &error)
>
>         /* Did we get an instance of AVAudioPlayer? */
>         if let player = self!.audioPlayer{
>             /* Set the delegate and start playing */
>             player.delegate = self
>             if player.prepareToPlay() && player.play(){
>                 /* Successfully started playing */
>             } else {
>                 /* Failed to play */
>             }
>         } else {
>             /* Failed to instantiate AVAudioPlayer */
>         }
>     }
>
> })
> ```

Hopefully this helps you.